# Prometheus not showing up count of 5xx errors

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I want to monitor SLI performance of my application, and i have my application in ec2. I am using prometheus and grafana. I have installed blackbox exporter for HTTP monitoring.
Now, i am trying to calculate total number of 2xx request and total number of 4xx,5xx errors.

This gives total number of req but i am expecting total no. of 2xx req, which doesn't show up.

```
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200", instance="10.0.0.37:9100", job="node"}
```

And when i run

```
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200", instance="10.0.0.37:9100", job="node"}
```

it shows the count as 0, though there are many points when my application was 5xx

What should be done to get total of 2xx req and total number of 4xx,5xx req?